# Slow response when calculating dynamic prices for hotels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I need to show the cheapest available accommodation for a hotel by calculating its price based on certain conditions like check-in date, check-out date, number of adults, and many others.
Right now what I'm doing is that I'm passing hotel ids as params and looping all hotel accommodations and calculate the price against each accommodation and then fetching the accommodation with the least calculated price.

**NOTE: Prices for a specific duration used to calculate the dynamic price is fetched using search kick gem and elasticsearch.**

```
@hotels = Lodging.where(id: params[:ids].try(:split, ',')).includes(:accommodations)
@hotels.map{ |hotel| hotel.accommodations.map { |accom| accom.cumulative_price(params.clone) } }
```

The issue now is that I need to show 18 hotels on a single page and each hotel has at least 4-5 accommodations which take about 4-5 seconds to respond. Can someone guide me how can I reduce this response time?

Comment: Faced the same issue. Any help would be grateful!!!